# Nested function explanation

Tags: javascript, svg

A little confused as to how my `circleAnimation` function is able to run a nested nameless function. Using snap.svg to animatie circles.

#### What's happening

I've set all my code inside of `setTimeout` function and then declared another function named `circleAnimation` which contains the code to run the first rotation of my circles.

I want my circles to infinitely animate so I found a way to achieve that with adding an anonymous function nested under the `circleAnimation` function I declare an anonymous `function(){});`

Inside the anonymous function I reset the animation to make it appear that it is infinitely animating.

**Here is where I get a little confused...**

Not sure **HOW** I was able to pass the anonymous `function(){});` as a callback..

I'm calling `circleAnimation();` at the top level of our functions scope to invoke the anonymous `function(){});` and then execute the second call at the bottom level of our `circleAnimation` function to execute the first function `circleAnimation`.

I'm just a little confused as to how the anonymous function is working...I know I have most it down but I feel there is a piece to the puzzle that I am miss-understanding. So some clarification would be great!

```
// animate circles
setTimeout(function(){
// call to anonymous function 
circleAnimation();
// circleAnimation animates circles
function circleAnimation () {
    // transformation 
    circles.stop().animate({
        transform:'r360,20,20'},10000,
        // anonymous function nested inside how dose this work? 
        function(){
        // reset animation
        circles.attr({
            transform:'rotate(0 20 20)'});
        // calling second function `circleAnimation`
     circleAnimation();
    });
  }
// timeout 
},5000);
```

Comment: That looks like it’s just a simple callback function …

Comment: So it's a call back to the original function which is `circleAnimate`

Comment: You don't "declare the anonymous function", you pass a function expression in a call, i.e. provide a callback.

Comment: I'm confused about what the confusion is. `circleAnimation` doesn't call an anonymous function anywhere; you explicitly declare `function circleAnimation`. The only anonymous function is the one you pass to `setTimeout` that executes in 5s.

Comment: So the function expression `function(){});` is passed in a callback to the `circleAnimation();` at the top level

Comment: Oh, I see the anon func inside `circleAnimation` now, passed to `animate`.  My bad, but I also find the over-commenting and lack of indentation of the inner anon func's body to be misleading at best.

Comment: Well I don't think there's to much commenting going on. Not like I HAVE lines and lines of comments..Just trying to be clear

Comment: _“So it's a call back to the original function”_ – no. It’s simply a function reference passed to the “outer” function call as a parameter, so that the outer function can call (execute) it at some point.

Comment: **I see!** its a *reference point function* which is passed to the outer function call as a param...Just not sure how it's passed as a param?

Comment: @BrentWhite—it's a *function expression*. The value passed is a reference to the function, just like an assignment: `var x = function(){}`, the function on the right is evaluated (not executed) and a reference to the function assigned to `x`. In the case of a *function expression* in a call, the reference is passed to the called function as a parameter.

Comment: @RobG perfect explanation :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous function expression is a *reference point* function that is then passed along to the outer function `circleAnimation`. This allows for the continuous cycle of animation.

#### Outer Func

No inner function to reset so just rotates once then stops

```
 // calling circleAnimation 
 circleAnimation();
  // animate circles
  function circleAnimation() {
    // one rotation
    circles.stop().animate({
        transform: 'r360,20,20'
      }, 10000);
  }
```

#### Inner Func

Now we add an inner function to `circleAnimation` which will repeat animation

```
 function() {
    // reset 
    circles.attr({
      transform: 'rotate(0 20 20)'
    });
    // passing inner function to outer function `circleAnimation`
    // this allows us to have a continuous loop 
    circleAnimation();
  });
```

#### All together

```
 function circleAnimation() {
 // rotate 360 
    circles.stop().animate({
        transform: 'r360,20,20'
    }, 10000,

 function() {
  // repeat animation start from 0
    circles.attr({
        transform: 'rotate(0 20 20)'
    });
   // pass anomn function to `circleAnimation`
   circleAnimation();
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if we break that down and look at it, we have

```
circles.stop().animate({...},10000, function(){...});
```

There it should be quite clear that a function is being passed as a parameter to `animate()`.

It just so happens that you call the surrounding function from within this, causing the whole proceedure to loop again.

Comment: Yes this is quite evident but what I am confused about is the anom function expression. To clarify -- it makes a call back to the original function `circleAnimate`

Comment: @BrentWhite — Yes. So what? Functions can call other functions.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to clarify my reasoning to make sure I am correct